# Python to Taradata connection

Tags: python, teradata

I am new to Python. Can someone tell me what software should I install (Pycharm??) so that I can write program to connect to Teradata. Any sample code in python to get a specific table extraction will be useful too for me.

Comment: See https://github.com/Teradata/python-driver

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.